# Find element in an array of object

Tags: arrays, swift

I created an array of objects:

```
var fullMonthlyList = [SimulationMonthly]()
```

The class here:

```
class SimulationMonthly {
    var monthlyMonthDuration: NSNumber = 0
    var monthlyYearDuration: NSNumber = 0
    var monthlyFullAmount: NSNumber = 0
    var monthlyAmount: Int = 0

    init(monthlyMonthDuration: NSNumber, monthlyYearDuration: NSNumber, monthlyFullAmount: NSNumber, monthlyAmount: Int){
        self.monthlyMonthDuration = monthlyMonthDuration
        self.monthlyYearDuration = monthlyYearDuration
        self.monthlyFullAmount = monthlyFullAmount
        self.monthlyAmount = monthlyAmount
    }
}
```

I just did append to populate it, now I want to find for example if they're an existing value, for example monthlyAmount equals to "194" by search in the array, how can I do ? I have tried filter and contains but I get errors.

What I've tried:

```
if self.fullMonthlyList.filter({ $0.monthlyAmount == self.monthlyAmount.intValue }) { ... }
```

Error:

> Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((SimulationMonthly) throws -> Bool)'

Comment: "I have tried filter and contains but I get errors." Can you show us what you did and which error did you get?

Comment: @Eendje for if self.fullMonthlyList.filter({$0.monthlyAmount == self.monthlyAmount.intValue}){ I get: Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((SimulationMonthly) throws -> Bool)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
if let sim = fullMonthlyList.first(where: { $0.monthlyAmount == 194 }) {
    // Do something with sim or print that the object exists...
}
```

This will give you the first element in your array where `monthlyAmount` equals `194`.

If you want **all** elements with that condition, you can use `filter`:

```
let result = fullMonthlyList.filter { $0.monthlyAmount == 194 }
```

If you don't need the object at all but you just want to know if one exists, then `contains` would be enough:

```
let result = fullMonthlyList.contains(where: { $0.monthlyAmount == 194 })
```

Comment: I recommend you use trailing closure syntax, though I can see the value of having `where:` for demonstrative purposes

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple playground example of filtering objects based on matching a property.  You should be able to expand it to your situation.

```
class Item {
    var value: Int

    init(_ val: Int) {
        value = val
    }
}

var items = [Item]()
for setting in 0..<5 {
    items.append(Item(setting))
}

func select(_ with: Int) -> [Item] {
    return items.filter { $0.value == with }
}

let found = select(3)
```

Comment: I'd recommend against writing a trivial function like `select()` in your example. It doesn't abstract much, but still adds an unnecessary layer of abstraction.

Comment: Rollback.  (If you're going to edit an answer to match your coding style, at least change it to something that compiles.)

Comment: Whoops, that should've been (0..<5).map(Item.init)